# Access Form with checkbox toggled textboxes to make visible

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Im trying to cut down on the clutter of my form since the data im getting can fill in more or less fields from my table.

as of right now im trying to build an event but I do not know the right syntax to use to create my event.

right now i have:

```
    = if toggle.onclick ="yes" then
    data.visible=true
    else
    data.visible=false
    end if
```

in the After Update tab of the Event tab.

I hope that gives you an idea of what im trying to do.

I have this on a test form so the only objects are:
checkbox name "toggle"
textbox name "data"

the text box is default to not visible at the moment.

my goal is to have a list of check boxes and once they are checked their corresponding text box would appear on a refresh.  this way the workers wont be intimidated by the amount of textboxes are on my current form. also will reduce the vast clutter on the current form.

Comment: ive been playing around with it and got an "invalid outside procedure" error with this: "=IIf([toggle]="yes",[Data].[Visible]=True,[Data].[Visible]=False)" in the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the 'Toggle' value will be True or False - not 'yes' or 'no'. Thus the following is what you need to toggle fields:

```
Private Sub Toggle_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Toggle = True Then
        Me.Data.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Data.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```